# How to find info on part efficiently?

Tags: components, datasheet

I'm not exactly a novice to electronics, but my problem is closely related, and I still feel like a complete newbie at those times.

I have no problem sourcing parts for new projects. Part of that is knowing a suppliers stock, and if my favorite two or three don't have them, I'll look to my semi-favorite suppliers. Usually, they have datasheets for their devices linked right in their web shops, so finding datasheets for those parts is no problem at all.

However, when trying to identify components (especially on older devices), I feel like running against walls.

Here's an example: I found a socketed IC with the label "IAM E3318" in a standard DIP package. I have no idea what this thing is, let alone found a datasheet for it. All I can deduce, is the manufacturer's short name is "IAM", and the part number is E3318.

However, this happens to me on many devices, especially older ones. Is there any standard method of seeking info about obscure parts like this, other than googling for hours?
Some datasheet aggregaters like Alldatasheet, sometimes give a positive result, only to link me to a completely other, unrelated part. Other times, I get a seemingly positive result, when clicking on the PDF symbol: "DATASHEET NOT AVAILABLE". This goes on and on, and is furiously frustrating.

What should I do? How should I go about looking for datasheets?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try is to attempt an advanced Google search.

I searched for "IAM E3318" with quotes to look for the exact phrase. The third result (this post being the first) was http://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102711348

Unfortunately it didn't help with a part number, but the manufacturer states Intel Corporation. Exactly how much this can be trusted, I cannot say, but it might give you more information to refine your search.

You could also try and add things like 16 (number of pins) or DIP (if you know the package).

Alternatively you can search for the 'main part' ie a motherboard, or whatever the assembly where you're mystery component is on. You never know, you might find a BOM or schematic. (try searching for that part number but only for PDFs e.g. 'NE555 filetype:pdf')

Hope that helps

Comment: OK, the filetype tip is helpful, as well as looking for main components and then looking for companion ICs. All the other things, I found myself. It is my standard way of looking for any kind of datasheet, etc. (A friend of mine used Duckduckgo and it pointed him directly to the site of the computer history museum.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever is worth (6 years late), this component "IAM E3318" is a resistor network of 330 Ohm, 8 resistors, all independent (measure opposing pins). I have the exact same component and ran into this question looking for information that I could not find anywhere.

The real answer came when I posted in the [EEVBlog forums](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/help-identifying-old-component/). There someone suggested what it could be, and after measuring the device, lo and behold it was that.

Apparently it is (or was) made by a japanese company called [IAM electronics](http://www.iam-ele.co.jp/) that specializes in Hybrid ICs and resistor networks. Look in the [products](http://www.iam-ele.co.jp/products/) section, and in particular, to [this PDF](http://www.iam-ele.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/RAD.pdf) of the equivalent parts (DIP resistor network), with what seem to be moder, but equivalent, markings.

EDIT: I contacted the Computer History Museum to correct the entry that says that that component is microprocessor, and they are in the process of correcting it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't beat yourself up. Technology evolves very fast and older devices fall out of use very easily.

Google is your best hope. If you don't find something easily here, you should look for newer alternatives.

That said here are a few resources that you can try:

[www.datasheets.com](http://www.datasheets.com)

[www.alldatasheet.com](http://www.alldatasheet.com)

[www.datasheetcatalog.com](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com)

[www.datasheets360.com/‎](http://www.datasheets360.com)

Comment: Well,  that's a given. But before I can do that, I must know what this part is in question, when repairing old stuff. The datasheet search engines you linked is exactly the kind I was referring in my question. They mostly point you to the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a site that I've used before (warning: it's a Russian site, so be careful)

http://www.systek.ru/marking.php

You can enter component markings and then sort by package. It's helped me understand a few mysterious SOT-3 components.

Also, this site is useful for help identifying the manufacturer of a part:

http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Guide_to_IC_manufacturer_logos